# how to get a template parameter type from a typedef inside of an object

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct foo {
    typedef T type;
};

foo<int> real;
foo<int>& a = real;
```

and I want to get the template type out of `a` - is that possible? I've tried the following:

```
a.type b;
decltype(a.type) c;
a::type c;
decltype(a::type) d;
```

but none of them work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `foo<int> a` you want: `decltype(a)::type e;`

After your edit, for `foo<int>& a` you want:

```
#include <type_traits>

std::decay<decltype(a)>::type::type e;
```

That's because in the latter case, `decltype(a)` is `foo<int>&`, so you first need to remove the reference (which is part of what `decay` does) to get at the underlying type.

Comment: And what if I have ```foo<int>& a = b;``` - meaning a reference?

Comment: @onqtam: Then you would ask a separate question :-)

Comment: @onqtam: (Or use `std::decay_t(decltype(a))::type`.)

Comment: @onqtam: Only if we're not going to play this game all night long. Think of the actual representative situation that you need to understand to solve your problem, and then make sure to ask *that* question. You want to ask a question in such a way that the answer is useful to solve your actual probelm.

Comment: edited - my real situation is exactly this - and the ```decay_t``` stuff didnt work (VS 2017).

Comment: @onqtam: see updated answer. (decay_t is from C++14, so you need to do what I say in the answer for C++11 instead.) [Demo](https://ideone.com/duriwx)

Comment: @KerrekSB The demo is wrong, you should use `b` at line 16. Otherwise `std::decay` becomes useless. Note that you used twice `decltype(a)` in the example.

Comment: @skypjack: well spotted, thanks. [Real demo](https://ideone.com/EqCRSQ). ("Test my code? Why test it, I've proven that it's correct.")

Comment: @KerrekSB You're welcome. I've proven that by simply writing it, isn't it? :-D